# Why 'list is list(list)' is false in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, identity

```
num = [1,2,3,4]
num == list(num)
```

It gives **True**, where as,

```
num is list(num)
```

gives **False**.

What is the difference between these two? What python does in both statements?

Comment: @Ashwani. Not quite a dupe. Tuple does not exhibit this behavior, but string and list do. Specific type matters here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` calls `list.__eq__` for the two lists, which compares the contents. `is` compares the object references. `is` returning `True` means that both names point to the same object in memory.

What the result tells you is that `list` *always* makes a shallow copy, even  if the input is another list. The reason is that `list` is a mutable type. You want to be able to modify one list without modifying the other, otherwise why bother calling the constructor at all?

The same behavior does not happen with `tuple`, which is immutable. `tuple(some_tuple) is some_tuple` will be `True`.

Answer (score 2):

`list()` creates a new list. The newly created list equal (`==`) to the original but not identical (`is`).